# Avoid duplicate URL-s with Apache FallbackResource directive

Tags: apache-2.4, fallbackresource

I'm using FallbackResource directive to route all web requests via front controller /index.php:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

It works great but one thing bothers me. It's the fact that /index.php is still available directly - same resource has two URL-s:

- `http://www.example.com/resource-path`
- `http://www.example.com/index.php/resource-path`

I was hoping FallbackResource will deal with this so that only main URL is available because this could pose a SEO problem. What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: It's shocking that nobody has answered this.  I am wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a solution in Apache for this. The only solution I've found for this is in handling it in PHP which almost defeats the purpose of using `FallbackResource /index.php` in the first place.

```
if (preg_match('#^/index.php#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $redirect = preg_replace('#^/index.php#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (empty($redirect)) {
        $redirect = '/'; // in case request is domain.com/index.php with no trailing slash
    }
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit;
}
```

This is not ideal but it works.  It's odd there's so little information about the duplicate URLs issue with `FallbackResource`.  Nevertheless, this solution did not suffice IMO so **what I did personally is go back to mod_rewrite**.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
```

Hope this helps you at least.  I tried a bounty but nobody seems to have an answer.

Comment: Thank you... problem confirmation is almost as good as solution :)